# Best practice for Jquery 'colorbox' signup form?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm creating a signup form that is launched using the jquery colorbox plugin. At present I have the form as an entirely seperate html file and I use the colorbox iframe function to display it like this:

```
<a class="iframe" id="register" href="/register.htm">Login</a>
```

My thinking behind using a seperate html form/iframe is that it avoids having the html code for the form included (and hidden) on every single one of my website pages, and possibly prevents any SEO disasters.

However, I want to perform jquery form validation on the user input when the user clicks on the 'signup' button. The simple solution I guess is to include the jquery library and custom validation code on the register.htm page, but this doesn't seem very clean....

Is there anyway to get the parent page to access the iframe and perform the form validation? I've tried the following which does not seem to fire or produce any errors:

```
$("#register").contents().find("#join_submit").click(function() { alert('booyahh'); });
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: To me it seems that the cleanest approach IS to include the validation and library on the form page, the jquery file will be cached so you are not requiring it to be re-downloaded, it will be a lot cleaner then messing around with cross frame scripting.

Comment: You could well be right. The only reason why I thought it to be 'unclean' was because I also need to do the same thing with a login, contact and a few other forms.